# How to get the value from XML file in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, xml, database

This is my xml code

```
<Hotelobjekt xmlns="http://www.dcs-caesar.de/hoteldaten" CRSSperre="false" Buchungssperre="false">
      <Hotelcode>AYTBLK0038</Hotelcode>
      <Hotelname>LIMAK ATLANTIS DE LUXE HOTEL &amp;amp; RESORT</Hotelname>    
    <Saisondefinition Saisonkuerzel="W16" DatumVon="2016-11-01" DatumBis="2017-04-06">
        <Saisonzeit Nummer="1">
          <Zeitraum DatumVon="2016-11-01" DatumBis="2016-11-18"/>
          <Zeitraum DatumVon="2016-12-25" DatumBis="2016-12-31"/>
        </Saisonzeit>
        <Saisonzeit Nummer="2">
          <Zeitraum DatumVon="2017-01-01" DatumBis="2017-03-06"/>
          <Zeitraum DatumVon="2016-11-19" DatumBis="2016-12-24"/>
        </Saisonzeit>
        <Saisonzeit Nummer="3">
          <Zeitraum DatumVon="2017-03-07" DatumBis="2017-04-06"/>
        </Saisonzeit>
      </Saisondefinition>
    </Hotelobjekt>



$items = simplexml_load_file($url);
print_r($items); // it's okey works
```

array output;

> SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [CRSSperre] =>
>   false [Buchungssperre] => false ) [Hotelcode] => AYTBLK0038
>   [Hotelname] => LIMAK ATLANTIS DE LUXE HOTEL & RESORT
>   [Saisondefinition] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array
>   ( [Saisonkuerzel] => W16 [DatumVon] => 2016-11-01 [DatumBis] =>
>   2017-04-06 ) [Saisonzeit] => Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object (
>   [@attributes] => Array ( [Nummer] => 1 ) [Zeitraum] => Array ( [0] =>
>   SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [DatumVon] =>
>   2016-11-01 [DatumBis] => 2016-11-18 ) ) [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
>   ( [@attributes] => Array ( [DatumVon] => 2016-12-25 [DatumBis] =>
>   2016-12-31 ) ) ) ) [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] =>
>   Array ( [Nummer] => 2 ) [Zeitraum] => Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement
>   Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [DatumVon] => 2017-01-01 [DatumBis]
>   => 2017-03-06 ) ) [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [DatumVon] => 2016-11-19 [DatumBis] => 2016-12-24 ) ) ) ) [2]
>   => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [Nummer] => 3 ) [Zeitraum] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array (
>   [DatumVon] => 2017-03-07 [DatumBis] => 2017-04-06 ) ) ) ) ) )

```
echo $items->Hotelcode."<br>";
echo $items->Hotelname."<br>";
```

this code works but I want to get the other code

```
<Zeitraum DatumVon="2017-01-01" DatumBis="2017-03-06"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do loop with child items

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
foreach($xml->Saisondefinition->Saisonzeit as $Saisonzeit) {
   echo $Saisonzeit['Nummer'] . "<br>\n";
   foreach($Saisonzeit->Zeitraum  as $Zeitraum ) { 
       echo $Zeitraum['DatumVon'] . ' - ' . $Zeitraum['DatumBis'] . "<br>\n";
   }
}
```

**[Demo on eval.in](https://eval.in/788592)**